# Not able to send email to Slack Channel through a linux system using mailx

Tags: slack, slack-api, slackware

I have written a script that is sending emails as an attachment to several email ids but email is not only being sent to Slack channel email address. Although I am able to send the email to slack channel email address if I send it through outlook.

Do I need to do any additional settings or anything in Slack ?

Answer (score 0):

It was because of some authorization issue by our ISP which was not allowing to send the email to Slack. It works fine if I tried to send email from my local to Slack.